# OSError: [WinError 995] - [asyncio, aiohttp]

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

This snippet of code is not working on my local machine!
I try the same snippet on a cloud server, and it's working like a charm!

I googled it, but I didn't find anything related, I do not know what is wrong!

Furthermore, I try reinstalling python, reinstalling libs, but the same error happens.
My local machine specifications:

Windows: Win11
Python Version : Python 3.10.5

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time


async def get_tasks(session):
    tasks = []
    for page in range(1, 10):
        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + str(page)
        header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        task = asyncio.create_task(session.get(url, headers=header))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        responses = await get_tasks(session)
        for response in responses:
            await response.text()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Mohamed Anan\GitHub\Web-Scraping\anan\async.py", line 25, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\Mohamed Anan\GitHub\Web-Scraping\anan\async.py", line 19, in main
    responses = await get_tasks(session)
  File "c:\Users\Mohamed Anan\GitHub\Web-Scraping\anan\async.py", line 13, in get_tasks
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1122, in send
    return self._coro.send(arg)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 535, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 542, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 986, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 709, in sock_connect
    return await self._proactor.connect(sock, address)
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
_OverlappedFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_OverlappedFuture finished exception=OSError(22, 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request', None, 995, None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 817, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 604, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
_OverlappedFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_OverlappedFuture finished exception=OSError(22, 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request', None, 995, None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 817, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 604, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
_OverlappedFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_OverlappedFuture finished exception=OSError(22, 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request', None, 995, None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 817, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 604, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
_OverlappedFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_OverlappedFuture finished exception=OSError(22, 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request', None, 995, None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 817, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed Anan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 604, in finish_connect
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

Comment: your machine has problem to connect URL - maybe you have to turn off firewall or antyvirus.

Comment: @furas  why?! Is there any technical reason about it?
I think it's just simple requests

Comment: this request use non standard `User-Agen` and firewall/antyvirus may thread it as virus or hacker's program. But firewall/antyvirus may have more complex system to detect unsecure requests. You could also try request without `async` - to check if problem is in different place. Of course can be also other problem: Google may detect that it is not real human and it may block access.